# How to pull a numerical value (varying in length) from the same position in a string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm fairly new to Python and can't quite find the wording to figure it out via Googling it or searching on here. I am attempting to write a line of code in Python to extract a certain number from an email subject line. I'm reading the email's data into a Panda dataframe (columns separated by subject, recipient, sender, etc). The number will always be in the same position but will vary in length (minimally 4, maximum 9).

For example:

```
Email Subject Line: 'No, I will submit changes: Action Required: RIC
CR 2.6.7.1-5 - Active Confirmation - Affected: Doe, John 012345 - Date
Sent: 01-02-2019'
```

Expected Result: `012345`

What I figure would be the best route is to take the string between the second to last and last '-' (i.e. Affected: Doe, John 123456). Once I have that, then extract 123456 from that substring. But, as stated previously, that number can vary in length from 4-9. Just like in the example, sometimes that number has a leading zero and I will need that to not fall off. On top of that, the name will obviously vary as well.

Is this even possible?

I've only attempted slicing on the string, but I feel like this will inevitably turn into a nightmare of an `if`-`else` scenario.

```
sixdigitnumber = df.subject[0][-30:][:6].strip()
```

I receive the expected result, but I feel that there is a smarter or more 'pythonic' way to do this. Please let me know if I could elaborate any more!

**Update #1:**

I have tried regular expressions as well, but not sure if this is still the best route?
way.

For example:

```
import re
regexpression= re.search('Manager: (.*) -', df.subject[0])
result = regexpression.group(1).rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
print (f'{result}')
```

Comment: Have you tried using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)?

Comment: Wondering if splitting from the end might work for you: `your_string.rsplit(' - ' ,2)[-2].rpartition(' ')[2]`... which could map to something like: `df['subject'].str.rsplit(' - ', 2, expand=True)[1].str.rpartition(' ')[2]` to apply to your dataframe column...

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '''Email Subject Line: 'No, I will submit changes: Action Required: RIC
CR 2.6.7.1-5 - Active Confirmation - Affected: Doe, John 012345 - Date
Sent: 01-02-2019'''

stringlist = string.split('-')
answer = stringlist[-4].strip()[-6:]
print (answer)
#012345
```

This answer assumes your title format is always the same. It will look for the `'-'` as the split criteria and split by that. Then it will look for the 4th from the back list element and take the last 6 digits.

Alternatively,

```
stringlist = string.split('-')
affectedlist = stringlist[-4].split()
anydigitnumber = affectedlist[-1]
print (anydigitnumber)
#012345
```

This can also work and it will get for you any number of digits in the last part of `John 012345`

Answer (score 0):

use **isdigit()**

```
s = "Email Subject Line: 'No, I will submit changes: Action Required: RIC
CR 2.6.7.1-5 - Active Confirmation - Affected: Doe, John 012345 - Date
Sent: 01-02-2019'"
```

the use of -1 come from the assumption that it's always in the same position

if you want the leading zero then a string will do:

```
print([a for a in s.split() if a.isdigit()][-1])
```

Comment: this appears to work as expected. Though, if I have a number that leads with a zero, it drops it. I would need the zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x= 'No, I will submit changes: Action Required: RIC CR 2.6.7.1-5 - Active Confirmation - Affected: Doe, John 012345 - Date Sent: 01-02-2019'
numbers=re.findall("(.*?)-",x)
for i in range(len(numbers[3])):
    if numbers[3][i].isdigit() is True:
        print (numbers[3][i:])
        break
```

if the pattern is consistent with the example you provided (searching for "-" to split the text then search for you numbers)

Answer (score 0):

you can split by a dash surrounded by spaces (as opposed to just a dash), and then it's easier to locate what you're looking for, namely the last "word" of the first-to-last "element":

```
string = '''Email Subject Line: 'No, I will submit changes: Action Required: RIC
CR 2.6.7.1-5 - Active Confirmation - Affected: Doe, John 012345 - Date
Sent: 01-02-2019'''

# first-to-last element (count backward from -1)
affected = string.split(' - ')[-2]
# last "word" (split assumes space/tab if nothing is provided)
number = affected.split()[-1]
```

if you need a number rather than a string just wrap the last line with `int`:

```
number = int(affected.split()[-1])
```

note that this will work for numbers of any length (and also preceding names of any length/number of words) so long as the structure is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>> import re    
 >>> s="""Email Subject Line: 'No, I will submit changes: Action    Required: RIC
... CR 2.6.7.1-5 - Active Confirmation - Affected: Doe, John 012345 - Date
... Sent: 01-02-2019'"""

>>> m=re.search(r'\b[0-9]{4,9}\b',s)
>>> m.group(0)
'012345'
```

use  \b for word boundaries to avoid matching something by accident